# CTE with Comparison Operator

Tags: common-table-expression

I'm getting a "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The multi-part identifier "cte.t" could not be bound."

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 2*AVG(TOT_ACCT_BAL) t   
            FROM    HSP_ACCOUNT)  
SELECT      HSP_ACCOUNT_ID,  
        TOT_ACCT_BAL  
FROM        HSP_ACCOUNT  
WHERE   TOT_ACCT_BAL > cte.t  
ORDER BY    TOT_ACCT_BAL
```

Can anyone tell me why? cte.t is a single value but looks like it can't be used with the > in WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Try including `cte` in the join

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 2*AVG(TOT_ACCT_BAL) t   
            FROM    HSP_ACCOUNT)  
SELECT      HSP_ACCOUNT_ID,  
            TOT_ACCT_BAL  
FROM        cte cross join HSP_ACCOUNT  
WHERE       TOT_ACCT_BAL > cte.t  
ORDER BY    TOT_ACCT_BAL
```